# Is it possible to edit intent with dialogflow after releasing the google home application?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-home

I make a self-made application using google home.
I am thinking about application and release to google (state callable from the Google home in general).
Is it possible to add / delete contents of intent in dialogflow after release?
Or do I need to apply again in order to apply changes after editing?

If you know someone, could you teach me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The action console recently received an update that supports an [Alpha/Beta testing channel](https://developers.google.com/actions/deploy/release-environments). With this, you can release a version, and then do additional development in Dialogflow. Once you're satisfied with this development, you can send it for review and then live and the Dialogflow version will be updated as well.

These only really apply if you're adding additional intents or changing the phrases in an intent. If you're just making changes to your back-end fulfillment, then you don't need to go through any of this.